# get file path from url

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdDyg.png)I have the url and now when I click on specific url then it should navigate to next page and open the file , here but it say that no such file directory exits.

```
 Future<File> getFileFromUrl(String url) async {
try {
  var data = await http.get(url);
  var bytes = data.bodyBytes;
  var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  File file = File("${dir.path}/mypdfonline.pdf");

  File urlFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  return urlFile;
 } catch (e) {
  throw Exception("Error opening url file");
 }
}
```

I should get filepath

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open an url, you need url_launcher plugin support or web view plugin support to load the URL content. But it looks like that your trying to access the file from assets, I'm thinking. If is that so, did you added your file in assets folder and adding the path inside pubspec.yaml file. Then you have to access the file using from assets.

If my answer not helpful, please elaborate your question a bit clear with some screenshot of your app, that what you are trying to achieve. Thank you.... Happy learning.

Comment: Please try to debug the app and pointed to file path. Then check whether the file path has been stored and successfully accessing or inside this code snippet



File urlFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  return urlFile;

Comment: I have store PDF files in firebase storage, and and I have all the URL in ListView format in UI, I want that when I click on any of the URL than that PDF file should get opened in another page.

Comment: That's what I am saying, please debug your app while clicking on the list item you are passing the url to next page to get loaded in PDF view. So check whether it was taking the URL or not. Please provide the Log response what it was returning after you entering the next page to load the url in pdf view.

Comment: Can i provide u the github link?

Comment: Give me sometime, I will build a sample app from my end to load the url of pdf file to be loading in pdf view and I will get back to you

Comment: Sure, it will be great to resolve your query faster.

Comment: the Github URL of my project is : https://github.com/iamjoytank/satsangreader.git

Comment: Your project is not running on iOS or on Android itself. Please take a look at your code first.

Comment: hey its running.

Comment: I think sir u have not pulled yet.

Comment: No I clone the code and running on Android studio. Let me cross check again

Comment: Sir I have solve the problem,but issue is that PdfView becomes blank on device rotation (portrait -> landscape). Does not reappear when the device is rotated back to portrait.

Comment: In that case, you need to write the piece of code to handle the states on screen orientation changes. You can get that code from developer website documentation itself.

Comment: Future main() async {
    await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
      ]);
    runApp(new MyApp());
  }

Comment: i have written this in main.dart file is it correct. or somewhere esle i needed to write.

Comment: Why are you referring multiple DeviceOrientations, we need to specify only Landscape and Portrait as Orientations to check the behaviour of the app.

Please check this link to verify your Device orientation and update the UI.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/orientation